# jQuery - Scale font-size to fill parent div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two 50% width divs inside a parent div. I would like to scale the font-size to always fill the height of the parent div when the window is resized.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="text">
    <div class="left-text text-fill">
    <span>Paragraph of text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right-text text-fill">
    <span>Paragraph of text</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery solution I found

```
function textfill(options)
{
    var fontSize = options.maxFontPixels;
    var t = $("span:first", this);
    var maxHeight= $(this).height();
    console.log(maxHeight);
    var textHeight;
    do {
        t.css({'font-size': fontSize});
        textHeight = t.height();
        fontSize = fontSize - 1;
    } while (textHeight > maxHeight);
    return this;
}
$(".textfill").each(textfill({maxFontPixels: 500}));
```

The problem I have is that `this` is referring to the outer wrapper div so it isn't finding a span. Why isn't `this` referring to the `<div class="text-fill">` which is the context of the function call? And how would I go about fixing it so that it is referring to that div and its child span?

Let me know if you need more code or clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I ended up just having to pass `this` as a parameter so the function understood what the context was.

```
$(".text-fill").each(function() {textfill(this, {maxFontPixels: 100})});
function textfill(that, options)
{
    var fontSize = options.maxFontPixels;
    var t = $("span:first", that);
    var maxHeight= $(that).height();
    var textHeight;
    do {
        t.css({'font-size': fontSize});
        textHeight = t.height();
        fontSize = fontSize - 1;
    } while (textHeight > maxHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```js
$(".text-fill").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), 
        fontSize = 500,
        $span = $this.children("span"),
        maxHeight= $this.height(),
        textHeight;
    console.log(maxHeight);
    $span.css({'font-size': fontSize});
    do {
        $span.css({'font-size': fontSize});
        textHeight = $span.height();        
        fontSize = fontSize - 1;
    } while (textHeight > maxHeight);    
});
```

```css
div.text > div {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
}
div.text > div > span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="text">
    <div class="left-text text-fill">
        <span>Paragraph of text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right-text text-fill">
        <span>Paragraph of text</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this help !